# Any possibility to fix camera null

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi can somebody help me to slowe problem with camera.main null error? pls thank you to you time :) Am try to fix my black screen but its not working at all.

If you can to slow it will be doupe and great but i dont now any more how to slov it at all, i try some camera vector3 and vector2 but nahhh i dont now really more i read so much tutorials, vids and nothing helped me to fix this issue and its anoying to much for my life. pls if you can fix it tell me how thank you again.

```
    private GameObject GameObjectHolder;

    private IEnumerable<Player> _players;
    private IEnumerable<LootItem> _lootItems;
    private IEnumerable<ExfiltrationPoint> _extractPoints;

    private float _playersNextUpdateTime;
    private float _exfilNextUpdateTime;
    private float _espUpdateInterval = 10f;
    private float _itemNextUpdateTime;
    private Camera cam;

    private bool _isESPMenuActive;
    private bool _isConfigMenuActive;
    private bool _showPlayersESP;
    private bool _crosshair;
    private bool _showItemESP;
    private bool _showValuables;
    private bool _showExfiljewEPS;


    private float _maxDrawingDistance = 400f;
    private float _maxLootDrawingDistance = 1500f;

    void Start()
    {
        cam = Camera.main;
    }

    public void Load()
    {
        GameObjectHolder = new GameObject();
        GameObjectHolder.AddComponent<Abso>();

        DontDestroyOnLoad(GameObjectHolder);
    }

    public void Unload()
    {
        Destroy(GameObjectHolder);
        Destroy(this);
    }


    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F5))
        {
            Unload();
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F11))
        {
            _isESPMenuActive = !_isESPMenuActive;

            if (_isConfigMenuActive)
                _isConfigMenuActive = false;
        }

    }


    private void OnGUI()
    {
        if (_isESPMenuActive)
        {
            DrawESPMenu();
        }

        if (_isConfigMenuActive)
        {
            DrawConfigMenu();
        }


        GUI.Label(new Rect(10f, 10f, 1000f, 500), "<COLOR=#FF0000>H</color><COLOR=#FF4600>I</color><COLOR=#FF8C00>S</color><COLOR=#FFD200>T</color><COLOR=#FFff00>O</color><COLOR=#B9ff00>N</color><COLOR=#73ff00>C</color><COLOR=#2Dff00></color><COLOR=#00ff00>I</color><COLOR=#00ff46></color><COLOR=#00ff8C>T</color>");

        if (_showPlayersESP && Time.time >= _playersNextUpdateTime)
        {
            _players = FindObjectsOfType<Player>();
            _playersNextUpdateTime = Time.time + _espUpdateInterval;
        }



        if (_showPlayersESP)
        {
            DrawPlayers();
        }


        if (_showExfiljewEPS && Time.time >= _exfilNextUpdateTime)
        {
            _extractPoints = FindObjectsOfType<ExfiltrationPoint>();
            _exfilNextUpdateTime = Time.time + _espUpdateInterval;
        }

        if (_showExfiljewEPS)
        {
            jewExfilEPS();
        }

        if (_showItemESP && Time.time >= _itemNextUpdateTime)
        {
            _lootItems = FindObjectsOfType<LootItem>();
            _itemNextUpdateTime = Time.time + _espUpdateInterval;
        }
        if (_showItemESP && !_showValuables)
        {
            DrawLoot();
        }
        if (_showItemESP && _showValuables)
        {
            DrawValuableLoot();
        }

        if (_crosshair)
        {
            DrawCrosshair();
        }
    }

    public void DrawCrosshair()
    {
        GuiHelper.DrawBox((float)Screen.width / 2f, (float)Screen.height / 2f - 5f, 1f, 11f, Color.yellow);
        GuiHelper.DrawBox((float)Screen.width / 2f - 5f, (float)Screen.height / 2f, 11f, 1f, Color.yellow);
    }

    private void jewExfilEPS()
    {
        foreach (var point in _extractPoints)
        {
            if (point != null)
            {
                float distanceToObject = Vector3.Distance(Camera.main.transform.position, point.transform.position);
                var exfilContainerBoundingVector = new Vector3(
                    Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(point.transform.position).x,
                    Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(point.transform.position).y,
                    Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(point.transform.position).z);

                if (exfilContainerBoundingVector.z > 0.01)
                {
                    GUI.color = Color.green;
                    int distance = (int)distanceToObject;
                    String exfilName = point.name;
                    string boxText = $"{exfilName} - {distance}m";

                    GUI.Label(new Rect(exfilContainerBoundingVector.x - 50f, (float)Screen.height - exfilContainerBoundingVector.y, 100f, 50f), boxText);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void DrawLoot()
    {
        foreach (LootItem item in _lootItems)
        {
            if (item == null)
            {
                break;
            }
            float num = Vector3.Distance(Camera.main.transform.position, item.transform.position);
            Vector3 vector = new Vector3(Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(item.transform.position).x, Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(item.transform.position).y, Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(item.transform.position).z);
            if ((double)vector.z > 0.01)
            {
                GUI.color = Color.cyan;
                int num2 = (int)num;
                string name = item.name;
                string text = string.Format("{0} - {1}m", name, num2);
                GUI.Label(new Rect(vector.x - 50f, (float)Screen.height - vector.y, 100f, 50f), text);
            }
        }
    }

    public void DrawValuableLoot()
    {
        foreach (LootItem lootItem in _lootItems)
        {
            if (lootItem == null)
            {
                break;
            }
            if (lootItem.name == null)
            {
                break;
            }
            if (lootItem.name == string.Empty)
            {
                break;
            }
            if (lootItem.name.Contains("key") || lootItem.name.Contains("tetriz") || lootItem.name.Contains("lion") || lootItem.name.Contains("virtexprocessor") || lootItem.name.Contains("defibrillator") || lootItem.name.Contains("bitcoin") || lootItem.name.Contains("transilluminator") || lootItem.name.Contains("prokill") || lootItem.name.Contains("video_card") || lootItem.name.Contains("document"))
            {
                float num = Vector3.Distance(Camera.main.transform.position, lootItem.transform.position);
                Vector3 vector = new Vector3(Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(lootItem.transform.position).x, Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(lootItem.transform.position).y, Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(lootItem.transform.position).z);
                if (num <= _maxLootDrawingDistance && (double)vector.z > 0.01)
                {
                    GUI.color = Color.cyan;
                    int num2 = (int)num;
                    string name = lootItem.name;
                    string text = string.Format("{0} - {1}m", name, num2);
                    GUI.Label(new Rect(vector.x - 50f, (float)Screen.height - vector.y, 100f, 50f), text);
                }
            }
        }
    }


    private void DrawPlayers()
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (Player player in _players.Where(plr => plr != null))
            {
                if (player == null)
                {
                    File.WriteAllText("greske.txt", "Here we go with player null error.");
                    return;
                }

                if (player.Transform == null)
                {
                    File.WriteAllText("greske.txt", "Player.Transform is null error");
                    return;
                }
                if (Camera.main == null)
                {
                    File.WriteAllText("greske.txt", "Camera.main is null error");
                    return;
                }

                float distanceToObject = Vector3.Distance(Camera.main.transform.position, player.Transform.position);
                Vector3 playerBoundingVector = new Vector3(Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(player.Transform.position).x, Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(player.Transform.position).y, Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(player.Transform.position).z);

                if (distanceToObject <= _maxDrawingDistance && playerBoundingVector.z > 0.01 && playerBoundingVector.x > -5 && playerBoundingVector.y > -5 && playerBoundingVector.x < 1920 && playerBoundingVector.y < 1080)
                {
                    var playerHeadVector = new Vector3(
                        Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(player.PlayerBones.Head.position).x,
                        Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(player.PlayerBones.Head.position).y,
                        Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(player.PlayerBones.Head.position).z);

                    float boxVectorX = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(player.Transform.position).x;
                    float boxVectorY = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(player.PlayerBones.Head.position).y + 10f;
                    float boxHeight = Math.Abs(Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(player.PlayerBones.Head.position).y - Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(player.Transform.position).y) + 10f;
                    float boxWidth = boxHeight * 0.65f;

                    Color guiBackup = GUI.color;
                    var playerColor = GetPlayerColor(player.Side);
                    var isAi = player.Profile.Info.RegistrationDate <= 0;
                    var deadcolor = player.HealthController.IsAlive ? playerColor : Color.gray;

                    GUI.color = deadcolor;
                    GuiHelper.DrawBox(boxVectorX - boxWidth / 2f, (float)Screen.height - boxVectorY, boxWidth, boxHeight, deadcolor);
                    GuiHelper.DrawLine(new Vector2(playerHeadVector.x - 2f, (float)Screen.height - playerHeadVector.y), new Vector2(playerHeadVector.x + 2f, (float)Screen.height - playerHeadVector.y), deadcolor);
                    GuiHelper.DrawLine(new Vector2(playerHeadVector.x, (float)Screen.height - playerHeadVector.y - 2f), new Vector2(playerHeadVector.x, (float)Screen.height - playerHeadVector.y + 2f), deadcolor);


                    var playerName = isAi ? "[BOT]" : player.Profile.Info.Nickname;
                    string playerDisplayName = player.HealthController.IsAlive ? playerName : playerName + " [MRTAV]";
                    string playerText = $"{playerDisplayName} [{(int)distanceToObject}]M";

                    var playerTextVector = GUI.skin.GetStyle(playerText).CalcSize(new GUIContent(playerText));
                    GUI.Label(new Rect(playerBoundingVector.x - playerTextVector.x / 2f, (float)Screen.height - boxVectorY - 20f, 300f, 50f), playerText);
                    GUI.color = guiBackup;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            File.WriteAllText("greske.txt", ex.ToString());
        }
    }



    private Color GetPlayerColor(EPlayerSide side)
    {
        switch (side)
        {
            case EPlayerSide.Bear:
                return Color.red;
            case EPlayerSide.Usec:
                return Color.blue;
            case EPlayerSide.Savage:
                return Color.yellow;
            default:
                return Color.yellow;
        }
    }

    public void DrawESPMenu()
    {
        GUI.color = Color.black;
        GUI.Box(new Rect(100f, 100f, 190f, 300f), "");
        GUI.color = Color.white;
        GUI.Label(new Rect(180f, 110f, 150f, 20f), "V-C 1.5");
        _showPlayersESP = GUI.Toggle(new Rect(110f, 140f, 120f, 20f), _showPlayersESP, " ESP IGRACI");
        _showExfiljewEPS = GUI.Toggle(new Rect(110f, 160f, 120f, 20f), _showExfiljewEPS, " IZLAZI ESP");
        _showItemESP = GUI.Toggle(new Rect(110f, 200f, 120f, 20f), _showItemESP, " LOOT ESP");
        _crosshair = GUI.Toggle(new Rect(110f, 240f, 120f, 20f), _crosshair, " NISAN");
        _isConfigMenuActive = GUI.Toggle(new Rect(110f, 260f, 120f, 20f), _isConfigMenuActive, " POSTAVKE");
    }

    private void DrawConfigMenu()
    {
        GUI.color = Color.black;
        GUI.Box(new Rect(400f, 100f, 190f, 300f), "");
        GUI.color = Color.white;
        GUI.Label(new Rect(480f, 110f, 150f, 20f), "POSTAVKE");
        GUI.Label(new Rect(410f, 140f, 150f, 20f), "ESP DALJINA: " + _maxDrawingDistance);
        _maxDrawingDistance = GUI.HorizontalSlider(new Rect(410f, 170f, 150f, 20f), _maxDrawingDistance, 0f, 1500f);
        GUI.Label(new Rect(410f, 200f, 150f, 20f), "LOOT DALJINA: " + _maxLootDrawingDistance);
        _maxLootDrawingDistance = GUI.HorizontalSlider(new Rect(410f, 230f, 150f, 20f), _maxLootDrawingDistance, 0f, 1500f);
        _showValuables = GUI.Toggle(new Rect(410f, 260f, 150f, 20f), _showValuables, "  VRIJEDAN LOOT");
    }

    private double GetDistance(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2)
    {
        return Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(x2 - x1, 2.0) + Math.Pow(y2 - y1, 2.0));
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

coud you give more information?
I think "Camera.Main null" is caused by a missung main camera in your scene, but i dunno cause i dont know how our scene is looking right now.
also i fond this:

File.WriteAllText("greske.txt", "Camera.main is null error");  [in DrawPlayers]

so my question is, if u mean that one, or a real console error when running unity? if you can, please make some screenshot, would be helpfull.